# How to compare two value in shell?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh

```
currentDNS=$(networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi)
GOOGLE="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

echo '+'$currentDNS'+'
echo '+'$GOOGLE'+'
```

it seems that GOOGLE == currentDNS  .

```
if [ "$currentDNS" = "$GOOGLE" ];then
   echo OKK
fi
```

but it return false

Comment: Perhaps networksetup returns a tab delimited string.  Put double quotes in your echo, and possibly pipe them to `cat -tve`

Comment: Try `echo "+$currentDNS+"` to see what is really stored in the parameter. Unquoted, any whitespace will be removed, and the resulting words will be printed by `echo` separated by a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this with the prefered bash test `[[ ]]` :

```
[[ $currentDNS == $GOOGLE  ]] && echo ok || echo >&2 "Not OK"
```

To figure out how is exactely the output of

```
networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
```

try this :

```
currentDNS="$(networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi)"
echo "[$currentDNS]"
```

and maybe

```
od -c <<< "$currentDNS"
```

and see if it's what you expect.